# Powershell - Where LastLogonDate is over 90 days from today

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to use the Search-ADAccount cmdlet to get all users where the LastLogonDate is over 90 days from today's date.  This script is to be ran each day and the requirements are to use Search-ADAccount and LastLogonDate that is over 90 days from today's date.  I know there are other ways to get the same info, but that's what I've been asked for from the team.

I pretty much just don't know how to do the math part on LastLogonDate but any sample scripts would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think SO is the best place to get recommendations for sample scripts.  If you find some on google and try to adapt them to your problem, we can help you with any problems you have then.

Comment: this may be a good starting point http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/search-adaccount-and-missing-15-days

Answer (score 2):

Got it figured out. Was looking for:

```
where-object {$_.LastLogonDate -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)}
```

Comment: Hi Rob, the answer you provided doesn't give any context to users who may be looking for the same answer. You need to post the commmand full syntax for this to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this, is not with `Search-ADAccount` but use `Get-ADUser` instead.

Using the answer provided by [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37604451/1163166) in response to his own answer, I would recommend the following:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties LastLogonDate | Where-Object {$_.LastLogonDate -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)}
```

This way we are searching all users, and asking AD to return the `LastLogonDate` variable of the object and identify the ones that have not logged on for the past 90 days.